# Salvar valor no banco para mesmo usuário

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Possuo uma página com um campo para cadastros que são gravados no banco de dados e na hora de gravar eu atribuo um ID de algum usuário aleatoriamente nesse cadastro.

Assim:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone1 = $_POST['phone1'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$client = $_POST['client'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblUsers` where grupo = 'contato' and ativo = 1 and periodo = 'manha' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $resultado = $pdo ->query($sql);
        if($resultado !== false)
            {
                foreach($resultado as $row)
                            {
                                $randomicId = $row['idVendedor'];
                            }
            }
```

No SQL acima que eu pego um ID aleatório dos meus usuários e atribuo a variável $randomicId.

Na hora de inserir no banco:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tblContacts(name,phone1,time,client,date,hourSend,qtd,origem,idUsuario)VALUES(:name,:phone1,:time,:client,:date,:hourSend,:qtd,:origem,:idUsuario)');
                        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name,':phone1' => $phone1,':time' => $time, ':client' => $client, ':date' =>$date, ':hourSend' => $hour , ':qtd' => $qtd, ':origem'=> $origem,':idUsuario'=>$randomicId));
```

Até aqui tudo ocorre normal, depois de salvo eu faço um select e exibo esses dados para os usuários logados de acordo com o ID deles.

Meu problema são os cadastros repetidos, pois eu queria gravar mesmo que fossem repetidos.

Por exemplo:

- No dia 1 o fulano fez um cadastro e gravou no banco para o usuário de ID 32.
- No dia 3 o fulano fez outro cadastro, mas dessa vez gravou no banco o usuário de ID 20.

Assim, eu estaria mandando 2 cadastros para o mesmo usuário.

Como verificar se o cadastro já existe e se já existir gravar no banco o mesmo ID do usuário ?

ps.: O campo 'phone1' dificilmente será igual, pois não existe 2 telefones iguais. Ele poderia ser usado para fazer a comparação.

Comment: Se uma pessoa preencher o telefone errado, irá refazer o formulário com o telefone certo... isso já quebraria a verificação pelo telefone.
O mesmo com o nome...

Comment: Entao , mas de que jeito eu poderia verificar ? Ps.: No campo do telefone , eu ja faço o tratamento para nao vir com numero faltando, letra , etc. o problema seria mesmo como voce falou , caso a pessoa digite errado .Mas  , ainda sim ,é dificil ocorrer .

Comment: Antes de gerar o ID aleatório você não pode dar um `SELECT` na `tblContacts` procurando pelo client e retornando o `idUsuario`? Se encontrar, usa ele, caso contrário você gera o aleatório.

Comment: Tentei fazer assim , mas nao esta gravando ID nenhum agora : $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblContacts` where phone1 = '$phone1' ";
    $resultado = $pdo ->query($sql);
     if($resultado !== false)
      {
       foreach($resultado as $row)
        {
         $randomicId = $row['idVendedor'];
        }
      }
      
      else
      {     SQL que ira gerar o ID aleatorio }

Comment: rapaz, dicas que me funcionam, eu gosto de fazer este tipo de cadastro, dos de muito elaborar, hoje tenho a função perfeita, visto que você tem Nome, Telefone, Time e Cliente, no caso, não sei exatamente como você usa este Time, mas, o nome, acredito que só exista uma pessoa com um nome e sobrenome no seu sistema que pertença ao time tal e tenha o telefone tal, o site você pode fazer para comparar todas elas, ou seja, quando digitar o nome e sobrenome, vai no banco de dados e procura, quando achar, mostra uma mensagem em verde para o usuário saber que está correto pois ele já fez isso, então a

Comment: Alguma das resposta ajudaram?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode estar fazendo de 2 maneiras, é mais um contorno do que uma solução. Mas espero que consiga ajudá-lo:

- Criar um campo que ele informe um tipo de **senha**, ou **código próprio de identificação** e então gravar no banco de dados utilizando como verificação.

***Exemplo:***

`Código de identificação: meunome123456`

---

OU

---

- Cria um `Cookie` com um **token** do usuário e guardá-lo para ser utilizado como verificação. **Porém tem o problema de o usuário apagar os dados de navegação**.

Você pode estar criando um `Cookie` da seguinte maneira:

```
$token = md5(uniqid(rand() . time(), true));
setcookie("Nome do Cookie", $token, time() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/"); // expira em 30 dias
```

Pode acessar o Cookie assim:
`$_COOKIE["Nome do Cookie"]`

Answer (score 0):

Erros de notice em PHP são apenas por tentar usar algo que não existe. Declere a variávei *$randomicId* fora dos blocos de if caso sua necessidade seja utilizá-la em locais distintos.

Comment: Boa tarde Fernando , o problema se eu declarar fora do IF , ele nao vai pegar o valor correto. Eu sei que a variavel é preenchida na condiçao verdadeira  ( se encontrar algum registro igual no banco  , o valor dela sera igual ao id do usuario gravado)  . Mas ao passar para a condiçao 'falsa' do IF , é que ele nao esta pegando .